# Power efficient oscillator topologies?

Tags: rf, analog, oscillator

I'm building an oscillator for a battery powered capacitive position sensor and I need it to have a high swing (>800 mV) at the output while keeping power consumption low enough. I'm feeding the output into the FPGA LVDS input so the oscillator must have a sufficient swing to drive it. Also it has to have large tuning range, a high ΔF/ΔC ratio and one side of the sensor must be grounded.

Right now I'm using a cascode Lampkin oscillator (see picture below), it has quite high sensitivity but it outputs only up to 600 mV into 4 pF load, consuming 2 mA at 3.3V.
I recently built a cross-coupled class D oscillator and I got 3 times Vcc at the output while consuming only 1.2 mA! But it's a differential oscillator so I can't use it because the probe is not differential and it can't handle the whole possible capacitance range. I also saw a [class-C Hartley oscillator](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Oscillators/osc21.php) that has higher efficiency by the looks of it but I don't quite understand how it works and how to change the circuit for my application.

So is there any oscillator topologies that are more power efficient than the one I'm using and still sensitive enough to capacitance changes?

[image]

Comment: Your schematic looks mighty "Hartley-ish" to me. You'll more-often see *two* resonating inductors rather than three (L6, L7 with L1=0nH) in a conventional Hartley. Major resonating currents should flow through Cprobe and L1+L6+L7. Your supply is 3.3V? A cascode of 2 DC-coupled transistors leaves little swing for your oscillator voltage.

Comment: What is the capacitance range of your probe?

Comment: @glen_geek well, yes, it's basically Hartley but with an additional inductor for further LC tank decoupling. Drops the swing a little but gives a significant increase in ΔC sensitivity. 
Yes, my supply is 3.3V but there's also unregulated voltage from a li-ion battery. So there's no benefits from having a cascode in my case? While designing this I was thinking about reducing Miller capacitance so I don't have to build a power hungry CE amplifier.

Comment: @TimWescott 6-18 pF

Comment: Getting power efficiency out of the thing should be more a matter of component choice and biasing -- there's no reason you couldn't bias that thing so that both stages are operating in class C, or close to it.  Alternately, you may be able to design the thing to start up quickly, and gate the power to it.  If it uses twice the current for 1/10th the time, that's an improvement.

Comment: @TimWescott I have trimpots instead of actual bias resistors and I set them for maximum output swing. 

_Alternately, you may be able to design the thing to start up quickly, and gate the power to it._

Not sure if I understand the purpose of that

Comment: Something tells me that L2 and L3 might be the culprits though. Those are just cheap 0805 film inductors. Aren't high SRF and low DC resistance required for RFCs?

Comment: L2 isn't doing much for you, at least not at 55MHz.  It has a reactance of around 550 ohms, so it looks more like a wire than a choke to R4.

Comment: @TimWescott is there a point in trying to increase the inductor value?

Comment: Do you know how to design oscillators by analysis?

Comment: @TimWescott no, I only have a few months of practical experience with oscillators, I'm actually new to RF in general.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get there from here.  Just driving 4pF at 50MHz (I assume that's the load of your LVDS) is going to take a good portion of a milliamp.

Comment: Sometimes trying to get one single circuit to do everything you want gets you too constrained. Have you considered optimizing your oscillator for everything but voltage swing and then have it followed by an amplifier?

Comment: @TimWescott oh, right. Should've calculated the reactance. It's hard to get used that such low capacitance input may consume so much current at hight frequencies. But still it would be nice if the amlpifier itself wouln't draw as much quiescent current as it does now.

Comment: @joribama it still has to be a highly efficient amplifier with very low quiescent current since I'm optimising current consumption. But I'll try that, thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should use a different approach for measuring the capacitance and communicating the result to the FPGA?  Like, drive a constant-frequency signal **out** of the FPGA, into a discriminator that uses the probe in its tank circuit, and then run the discriminator output to an ADC?

Comment: That was the initial idea but the probe's Q is not high enough, so the sensitivity with this method is not satisfactory.